# Hand detector in Python

Tags: python, opencv

Not just #cv2putText, add print(totalFingers)
Can you get the value?
I don't want to show the numbers in the image

My code is as follows.

```
    from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.5, maxHands=1)

while True:
    # Get image frame
    success, img = cap.read()

    # Find the hand and its landmarks
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)

    lmList =[2]
    if lmList:
        bbox = bboxInfo[0]['bbox']
        fingers = detector.fingersUp()
        totalFingers = fingers.count (1)

       # cv2.putText(img, f'Fingers:{totalFingers}', (bbox[0] + 200, bbox[1] - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # 顯示
    cv2. imshow("Image", img)
    print()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release(totalFingers)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

``
bbox = bboxInfo[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

The bug: `totalFingers` is defined only `if lmList:`. However it looks like lmList is False/empty/None and you try to you use totalFingers which is not defined.

```
Example 1:

    lmList = [2]
    if lmList:
       totalFingers = 7
    print(totalFingers)

Example 2:
    # this is the bug 
    lmList = None
    if lmList:
       totalFingers = 7
    print(totalFingers)
```

Comment: Can you make it more clea

Comment: try to run both examples. Try to notice the difference

Comment: bbox = bboxInfo['bbox']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `bbox = bboxInfo['bbox'] ` - do you understand what is wrong?

Comment: I can't find the reason sorry

Comment: Can't it be a string

Comment: I changed the program

Answer (score 0):

I think You need this...

```
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

def NoOfFingers():
    wCam, hCam = 640, 480
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3, wCam)
    cap.set(4, hCam)
    pTime = 0

    detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.75, maxHands=1)

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        hands, img = detector.findHands(img)
        if len(hands)!=0:
            break

    if len(hands)!=0:

        fingers = detector.fingersUp(hands[0])

        noOfFingers = fingers.count(1)
        return noOfFingers

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print(NoOfFingers())
```